# single user login Determination

Tags: asp.net, security, web-applications

I'm writing a web application and I want to make it as a single user app(no login in other system even other browsers).

One solution is to set a table field in my db when the user is logged in and reset in when he is logged out.

but the problem is when an unexpected event happens(like browser crashing, electricity gone, network probs, etc).

What is the best way to come across this goal?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

there is not way you can do it.

Imagine user A and B behind a router that does NAT, that mean they both have the same IP address on internet.

How do you determine which is which wihtout storing some data in the browser ?

If you store data in the browser, then you can't have a single login for different browser

Comment: how to determine the storing data? Can I use cookies to check my use login?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct, you should set a filed in db for this operation.
but for browser crashing or other events, you should set a timer, if user doesn't do anything in mentioned time, you should logged him out.
You can write a console application and put that in task scheduler of server or if you use Linux server you should use Cron Jobs.
In other way you can write a sql job for Sql Server Database.

Update:
You can set a field in your database for last Operation time.
when user click on some link or worked with pages (i mean the operations that send requests to server) you should update the field with current time.
and you should warn user if not do anything for example in 30 minutes,the system logged the account of.
the Console application, that you put in task scheduler, check the current time and the last operation time, if the difference more than 30 minutes you know the user must be logged of.

Comment: _if user doesn't do anything in mentioned time_ => how to understand it? _write a sql job for Sql Server Database_ => why? to accomplish users activity?

Comment: How to accomplish through coding? Could you give me example?Thx